# Autoscaling on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

Hey my iOS app is very simple and instead of messing with the auto-layout feature of Xcode is there a way to just programmatically size the screen for each resolution. I am using the storyboard feature of Xcode, but I can't seem to figure this out. I googled it quite extensively, the only thing I found was Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > Reset to...

That works well, except it always squishes my images. I try to set a forced height on them and then everything goes crazy!

So Is there any techniques that shrink everything in the view by 10% vertically?

Thanks, Krkto

-BTW screen is a UIView

-edit- also When I set the autolayout to "Reset to suggested contraints in..." and I call a animation that scrolls the view up, it scrolls the assets up slowly, while the background goes up in a normal fashion.

Comment: What is this screen? A UIView?

Comment: Thanks Jino, silly mistype lol

Comment: So you want to know how to make a UIView programmatically?

Comment: Oh no, I want to scale all the assets inside the view by a certain percentage.

Comment: what are these assets?

Comment: images, texts, buttons

Comment: I feel like I a missing something obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it with AutoLayout.

- Setup your view in IB / Storyboard
- Setup the constraints

Since you want to scale subviews - set their height and width constraints.

So - Width constraint: 
Do this by

- ctrl + drag inside the UIView from left to right (Or visa versa)

When you stop dragging a  pop up will show with two options: choose Width.

So the same for height - just ctrl + drag from within the UIView you want to scale, top to bottom or bottom to top and when the pop up shows, click height.

Now that your constraints are set - find them in the left panel that shows all your UIView objects for your IB / Storyboard. They will be in the same UIView you made them in.

Now, ctrl + drag them to your view controller - these will create `NSLayoutConstraint` `IBOutLets

Example:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint;
```

Now - when you want to update the height constraint (and width) - in code, do something like this:

```
self. heightConstraint.constant = 10; // new Size

[self.view layoutSubviews]; //Causes setNeedsDisplay to be called on all subviews in UIView
```

That's all there is to it. You could put this code inside a UIView animation and it will animate nicely, too. Just use some simple math to calculate the size to whatever % you want.

If you look in IB / Storyboard - you will see where the constraints in the left side of Xcode are shown, it will give you there current constant value.

Example:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What your missing is constraints. [raywenderlich on autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

This tutorial provides what I believe your looking for.

Comment: Thanks, its a pretty goo tutorial. But i'll give it an another round. TBH is more complicated then I really want. I just want it to scale equally from one resolution to another. I guess I come from a game dev background and that seems pretty standard to me.

Comment: I'm the same way. I always stay away completely from auto layout. I always make my stuff programmatically. It is more typing, but I feel more in control that way.

Comment: There has to be an easier way. Yeah I feel you, but being able to drag and drop stuff is an amazing thing.

Comment: You guys really need to spend more time with Auto-Layout. It can do what you need it to, with a few lines of code and its simple to programmatically  change the constraints when needed. So this whole scaling by x% is as simple as taking the constraint for the UiView you want to scale and apply some math to it and it will change shape on screen.

Comment: @Tander Would you mind giving an example?? What you described is exactly what I am looking for. But I thought the point of Auto-layout was to not do anything programmatic. I don't mind either way. Just something that works! :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what @krtko really wanted was to turn off Auto-Layout, Size Classes and put the app into auto-scale mode. For simpler screens this is just an easier way to handle the four screen sizes than Auto Layout. The "struts and springs" (Autoresizing) function can still be used to define what happens as the screen real-estate grows or shrinks (particularly in the case of iPhone 4 / iPhone-on-iPad mode).

The key is to use the UILaunchImages key in info.plist and specify images for only 320x480 and 320x568. This throws app into a mode where the 6 and 6+ sizes are automatically displayed as an iPhone 5 scaled up. You lose the benefits of high resolution, but gain a lot of time not having to play with AutoLayout and deliver lots of image files in all the resolutions. Great for MVPs and quick prototypes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW28

Note that in this environment, the Assistant Editor / Preview function does not work properly; it shows what the view would look like if rendered through the usual scaling mechanisms, not the automatic scaling that is used when compiled. The simulator will show the correct layout.

[image]